# Total count of cells with values(filtered) within range of date

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-docs

I'm trying to count the number of cells with values within specific date range. I used subtotal to count only the visible cells but I don't have any ideas to insert specific formula for the range of dates. This is the formula I used:

```
= SUBTOTAL(3,'REINSPECTION W/ OVR'!B3:B)
```

[image: Here's the screenshot of my sheet]

For example, I want to see the Total of Reinspection w/ OVR within January 1, 2023 - March 31, 2023, the value will change based on this tab below:

[image]

I only want to count the visible cells with values in column B at REINSPECTION W/ OVR sheet.

Hopefully someone will help me. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `countifs`?

Comment: I already tried it but it also count the hidden cells.

Comment: I think this is a X-Y problem.
What manual filter do you apply before you trying to count the values from that selection? If you involve the filter condition(s) in a SUMPRODUCT or COUNTIFS-formula, like suggested by @Tedinoz, you get your end result.

Comment: I think you're looking for something like: `=SUMPRODUCT(('REINSPECTION W/ OVR'!F3:f>B3)*('REINSPECTION W/ OVR'!F3:f<C3))`

Comment: I don't think it's wise to share actual data though.

Comment: Will try your suggested formula tomorrow at work.

Comment: I tried this formula =SUMPRODUCT(('REINSPECTION W/ OVR'!F3:f>B3)*('REINSPECTION W/ OVR'!F3:f<C3)) but it also counts the hidden cells too.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the range of dates in some cells?? You could do something like this:

```
=COUNTA(FILTER('REINSPECTION W/ OVR'!B3:B,'REINSPECTION W/ OVR'!F3:f>B3,'REINSPECTION W/ OVR'!F3:f<C3,BYROW('REINSPECTION W/ OVR'!B3:B, LAMBDA(each,SUBTOTAL(103,each)))))
```

SUBTOTAL with the code of 103 doesn't count the values that are hidden. Inserted inside a FILTER will filter out those hidden values. Please try it out, or share some sample file to test it

Comment: I already solved it. I forgot to close the thread. Here's what I used;

=COUNTIFS('REINSPECTION W/ OVR'!F3:F1000,">="&B3,'REINSPECTION W/ OVR'!F3:F1000,"<="&C3,map('REINSPECTION W/ OVR'!F3:F1000,lambda(z,subtotal(103,z))),1)

Thanks for the response tho.

Comment: Yes, that would do the same process! Good one!